# Play 2.0 with Eclipse 3.6, Scala template editing

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I´m new to Play and Scala world, so I´m needing some help to figure out how can I edit the scala template files using Eclipse. I already installed scala ide 2.9 but when I try to edit the index.scala.html, the contents of the file aren´t editable...

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there an error message?  What happens when you try to edit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I experienced this just recently, too, but lucky for you I made the full migration from IntelliJ to Eclipse.

There is some setting up you need to do with the Scala templates, but one of the easiest ways to get it done is following these steps:

**Step 1: Add file extensions**

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml

[image: editor preferences]

Be sure that your file extensions are properly added to the file associations.

**Step 2:**

Look at the associated editor. In the image above you'll see that the only associated editor with `*.htm` is `Web Browser`. So you'll need to hit the "Add..." button to add the Scala editor. Don't forget to set it as default :)

**Step 3:**

[image: right-click context menu for html scala editor]

Right-click on your Scala template and be sure that you are choosing the right editor. You can also use this to switch between editors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the long time, but it really solved my problem! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I think it's a common problem with documentation that's hard to find ;)