# Where do I find and install the template editor for ScalaIDE?

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, scala-ide

From the searching I've done, I've managed to find these two links that are relevant:

[Answered question on Stack Overflow that is similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215382/scala-ide-play-2-eclipse-plug-in-not-highlighting-syntax-for-scala-html-templa)

The problem with the first link is that the answer doesn't explain how to find and install the template editor (which is what fixed the issue with syntax highlighting).
Also, the last comment on the chosen answer asks where they should go about finding the template editor and was never responded to. (This was asked May 11, 2013 and has two rep)

[Unanswered question on Stack Overflow that is identical to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112642/how-do-i-get-the-template-editor-for-eclipse-scala-skd?lq=1)

The problem with the second link is that it was asked June 9, 2014 and is still unanswered.

When I look in preferences, I am unable to see the template editor as one of the options.
The link below shows a screenshot I took of the preferences.

[Link to a picture showing the lack of a template editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqpZt.png)

Other information that may be useful:

-Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK Version: 4.3.0

-OS X Yosemite Version: 10.10.1

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702701/play-2-0-with-eclipse-3-6-scala-template-editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to download a distribution of the Scala IDE from here:

http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html

As mentioned on that page, it bundles Eclipse Luna and comes with Play2 support included.

Alternatively, you can install just the plugins you need on top of your Eclipse installation from one of the two update sites listed here:

http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

Note that due to binary incompatibilities between Kepler (4.3.x) and Luna (4.4.x), there are two different update sites for the Scala plugin.

> Make sure to enable the Play support as well (under "Scala IDE plugins")

[image]

Comment: Downloading the Luna version of Scala IDE from http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html did the trick perfectly, thanks!